# notifications in asana using nodejs asana module

Tags: node.js, api, asana-api

I am trying to put post notifications to asana from a developed application for deployment and code issues.
 I am using nodejs module 'asana' for that but I could not find the proper method to do that.
 Can you please help me post notifications or comments in asana to achieve that.
Creating a task and adding comments to that task through the application on different events like deployment, onError, etc will work but I could not get the proper documentation to do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asana does not have ant complete api support for conversations https://forum.asana.com/t/creating-team-project-conversations-from-api/1184

The only way to put conversations on asana using node module support for asana or in similar language:

- create a task in asana
- post comments on that task https://developers.asana.com/docs/#asana-tasks 
  here is the sample code to do that

```
     // asana-notifications.js
    const asana = require('asana')
    const logger = require('your-logger')
    module.exports = {
     sendAsanaNotification: async (notification) => {
       try {
         var personalAccessToken = 'your-asana-token'
         var client = asana.Client.create().useAccessToken(personalAccessToken)
         return await client.tasks.addComment('your-task-id', { text: Date() + notification })
       } catch (error) {
         logger.error({
           details: error.message || error,
           errorStack: error,
           message: 'error sending asana notification'
         })
       }
     }
    }

    // file in which you want to use it
    const notifications = require('asana-notificaitons')
    asana.sendAsanaNotification(JSON.stringify('your notification'))
    }
```

This is the workaround that I have right now.
I am using different tasks to put different notifications.